# Keep Bioshock Infinite FOV constant

Tags: technical-issues, pc, bioshock-infinite

Is there a way to keep the FOV (Field of View) constant in the PC version of the game?

I really don't like how the FOV and mouse sensitivity varies when the character is running, and if possible would like to disable it completely.

Comment: I've not noticed any variation in the mouse sensitivity between running and not running, and the FOV adjustment is minor. I think the adjustment is a feature of the Unreal Engine though, and I couldn't find anything in config that would help you out.

Comment: It seems it's built upon UE3, the same thing Borderlands runs on. I remember there was a question like this for Borderlands, the solution was to bind a command that applies the new FOV value on the `run forward` key. If it's not enough, it was recommended to also bind this on other keys. I don't think there was a solution that would make the FOV value constant, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change and keep the FOV by doing the following:

1. First go to *C:\Users\ (username) \Documents\My Games\BioShock Infinite\XGame\Config*
2. Open *XUserOptions.ini* with any text editor, and then look for the line that starts with "MaxUserFOVOffsetPercent" then tweak the value to your liking.
3. Save the file *(make sure you are saving it as an .ini file and not as a .txt file)*.
4. Right click the *.ini* file and click on "Properties". Under attributes tick "Read-only" and then press "Apply".

This should allow you to change the FOV and keep it. The downside it rather large though since the game cannot modify the *.ini* file this may cause problems.